# Heap memory is growing more after taking picture using Camera

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a memory problem when using camera in my app. I have used SurfaceView for taking picture. After taking the picture in log cat it is showing Heap memory grow to 30 mb sometimes  40mb also. Because of this some times app is crashing also "OutofMemoryException". Here I am providing my code . Please help me.

```
surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


capture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW,
                    myPictureCallback_JPG);
            capture.setClickable(false);
        }
    });



PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        System.out.println("myPictureCallback_RAW");
    }
};




 PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {


        try {

            bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0,
                    arg0.length);

        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                Toast.makeText(FromCamera.this, "Please try again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(FromCamera.this, "Please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        capture.setEnabled(false);
        buttonBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonBack.setEnabled(true);
        buttonDone.setEnabled(true);
    }
};



ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        System.out.println("onShutter");
    }
};
```

I have tried force Garbage Collection, but still no use.

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    previewing = false;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue.Have you solved?Please reply.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it using the tips provided in this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inspect the memory allocations of your app, see a related post [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) (it also has some great articles linked at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Are you releasing your camera after using? After you are done with taking the picture try to release the camera with camera.release(), and evaluate the memory usage again.

Another thing you can try is to destroy the surface, after you have used it, and see if that helps.

Comment: I am releasing the camera as well as destroying the surface...check updated code in my post

Comment: Can you put some logs and see, if you are actually entering the surfaceDestroyed method?

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with  Bitmap , the Garbage collector May fail some time ... when your are not use the bitmap make sure that you release the Bitmap memory

```
if(!mBitmap.isRecycled())
mBitmap.recycle();
```

which release the bitmap memory